# Realm Swift: Update all model objects and remove migration

Tags: swift, realm

I added a field to my realm model in swift, and performed the migration, but even after I deleted all objects, I still get an error when I take the migration block out of my appdelegate. Does the migration block of code have to stay forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Since you used a migration to bump the `schemaVersion` number of the Realm file, that migration block is required with the assumption that another migration may be required in future.

If you want to completely reset the migrations and remove the migration block, you'll need to delete your Realm file from disk and recreate it (i.e., simply deleting just the objects isn't enough).

Comment: Any idea how can we do that in swift?Please I really need help.I want to clear realm file on device and recreate it

Comment: Yep! Since this Stack Overflow question, Realm added the ability to automatically delete Realm files and start over if a migration was required. It's the `deleteRealmIfMigrationIsNeeded` property of the `Configuration` object in Realm Swift: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm/Configuration.html#/s:vVC10RealmSwift5Realm13Configuration28deleteRealmIfMigrationNeededSb

Comment: Thanks,TiM,really helpful.:D